# Can I partition an external hard drive for xbox one?

Tags: xbox-one

I'm thinking of buying an external drive for my Xbox One but I would also like to use it for my PC storage.

The feature of partitioning an external HDD was available on the 360, which would use a selected amount of the memory stick for Xbox files and the rest could be used for other uses, like file storage for PC.

Is this partitioning feature available on Xbox One?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. When the Xbox One finds the drive you will have to decide if it is used for games or media. If you pick games then Xbox will format the whole drive. I am trying to find a work around but at the moment the answer is no.